# How to iterate over results of query

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I am creating a function in pgsql script language, and what I want to do in this point is iterate over the results of a query and for each row do something specific. My current try is the following, where `temprow` is declared as `temprow user_data.users%rowtype`. The code in question is the following:

```
FOR temprow IN
        SELECT * FROM user_data.users ORDER BY user_seasonpts DESC LIMIT 10
    LOOP
        SELECT user_id,user_seasonpts INTO player_idd,season_ptss FROM temprow;
        INSERT INTO user_data.leaderboards (season_num,player_id,season_pts) VALUES (old_seasonnum,player_idd,season_ptss);
    END LOOP;
```

However I get the following error from this: `ERROR:  relation "temprow" does not exist`. If it's clear what I want to be done, could you point to me the right way to do it?

Comment: The right way to do it would be: "dont't iterate". What you seem to do is perfectly feasable using plain SQL : `insert into leaderboards(a,b,c) select x,y,z from users;`

Comment: As I noticed in the answer, `old_seasonnum` is not selected at this point from `user_data.users`, but in a previous point.

Comment: It is allowed to use a constant (or a variable, in plpgsql or in prepared statements) where an expression is needed: `insert into foo(a,b,c) select 42, y, z from bar;` Note: in your code `old_seasonnum` is not even defined.

Comment: I just put here the part of the code I had the problem at, it is defined in previous sectors in the actual code. If you feel it's necessary, I will put the whole code here.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

`temprow` is a record variable which is bound in turn to each record of the first `SELECT`.

So you should write:

```
FOR temprow IN
        SELECT * FROM user_data.users ORDER BY user_seasonpts DESC LIMIT 10
    LOOP
        INSERT INTO user_data.leaderboards (season_num,player_id,season_pts) VALUES (old_seasonnum,temprow.userd_id,temprow.season_ptss);
    END LOOP;
```

This loop could be further simplified as a single query:

```
INSERT INTO user_data.leaderboards (season_num,player_id,season_pts)
SELECT old_seasonnum,player_idd,season_ptss FROM user_data.users ORDER BY user_seasonpts DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Is `FOR`/`temprow` a cursor? Does it do any locking?

Comment: Yes it is a cursor, but no locking is done on the `users` table

Comment: The problem with the simplified single query is, `old_seasonnum` is not selected from `user_data.users` table, but from a previous select and will be used at this point.

Comment: Is this a local variable of the procedure? Then you can use it as `SELECT old_seasonnum AS season_num ...`

Comment: To someone who wonders,

DECLARE temprow RECORD;

Comment: Is the ORDER BY user_seasonpts necessary?

Comment: @ennth, yes it is necessary because of the `LIMIT` clause, since the statement inserts only the first 10 records according to the specified order.

Answer (score 18):

For future reference, I want to emphasise [Thushara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12162813/thushara-buddhika) comment on the accepted answer

On Postgres@12 the following would work:

```
DO $$
DECLARE temprow RECORD;
BEGIN FOR temprow IN
    SELECT * FROM user_data.users ORDER BY user_seasonpts DESC LIMIT 10
  LOOP
    INSERT INTO user_data.leaderboards (season_num,player_id,season_pts) VALUES (old_seasonnum,temprow.userd_id,temprow.season_ptss);
  END LOOP;
END; $$
```

Answer (score 15):

A function that loop through the select and use loop item values to filter and calculate other values,

```
CREATE FUNCTION "UpdateTable"() RETURNS boolean
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
DECLARE
    TABLE_RECORD RECORD;
    BasePrice NUMERIC;
    PlatformFee NUMERIC;
    MarketPrice NUMERIC;
    FinalAmount NUMERIC;
BEGIN
    FOR TABLE_RECORD IN SELECT * FROM "SchemaName1"."TableName1" -- can select required fields only

        LOOP
            SELECT "BasePrice", "PlatformFee" INTO BasePrice, PlatformFee
            FROM "SchemaName2"."TableName2" WHERE "UserID" = TABLE_RECORD."UserRID";

            SELECT "MarketPrice" / 100 INTO MarketPrice FROM "SchemaName3"."TableName3" WHERE "DateTime" = TABLE_RECORD."DateTime";

            FinalAmount = TABLE_RECORD."Qty" * (BasePrice + PlatformFee - MarketPrice);

            UPDATE "SchemaName1"."TableName1" SET "MarketPrice" = MarketPrice, "Amount" = CFDAmount
            WHERE "ID" = CFD_RECORD."ID"; -- can update other schema tables also
        END LOOP;

    RETURN TRUE;
END
$$;
```

Answer (score -1):

@Tazahi Leh perfect - thank you!
But don't forget a semicolon after END :)

```
DO $$
  DECLARE temprow RECORD;
  BEGIN FOR temprow IN
    SELECT * FROM user_data.users ORDER BY user_seasonpts DESC LIMIT 10
    LOOP
      INSERT INTO user_data.leaderboards (season_num,player_id,season_pts) VALUES (old_seasonnum,temprow.userd_id,temprow.season_ptss);
    END LOOP;
  END;
$$
```

Comment: Thanks, but this should've been written as a comment on my answer then :). 
@moffeitje already fixed it in my answer (thanks!)