# Postgresql Insert into table values with multiple records

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, subquery, sql-insert

I need to insert into a table (groupL) two rows (custId, aName). custId is constant while aName is multiple records of variable size based on a nested subquery.

That subquery is:

```
SELECT aName 
FROM artwork 
WHERE artwork.title IN (SELECT title 
                        FROM classify 
                        WHERE NEW.g_name = classify.g_name);
```

I've tried a lot of SQL but I really don't get it. I'm looking for something that if we have two rows in aName (name1, name2) it'll do something like

```
INSERT INTO groupL(custId, aName) 
    SELECT custIdConstant, name1 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT custIdConstant, aName 
                      FROM groupL 
                      WHERE custId = custIdConstant AND aName = name1);

INSERT INTO groupL(custId, aName) 
    SELECT custIdConstant, name2 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT custIdConstant, aName 
                      FROM groupL 
                      WHERE custId = custIdConstant AND aName = name2);
```

How do I do this? Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Where does `NEW.g_name` come from? I realize you said this is from a subquery but I think that's going to be relevant info.

Comment: It's based on a trigger when a record is inserted. It's not relevant for the iteration thing I'm trying to figure out

Answer (score 0):

You can do in one Go but  you need to have the ids before hand, if you want to compare and of course a FROM clause

```
CREATE tABLe groupL(custId int , aName TEXT)
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE
> ```

```
CREATE TABLe aName (name1 TEXT, name2 TEXT)
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE
> ```

```
INSERT INTO aName VALUEs ('A','B')
```

> ```
> INSERT 0 1
> ```

```
DO $$
DECLARE  
   custIdConstant integer := 10;  
BEGIN  
INSERT INTO groupL(custId, aName) 
SELECT custIdConstant, name1 FROM aName  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM groupL WHERE custId = custIdConstant AND aName = name1);

INSERT INTO groupL(custId, aName) 
SELECT custIdConstant, name2 FROM aName WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM groupL WHERE custId = custIdConstant AND aName = name2);

END $$;
```

> ```
> DO
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM groupL
```

| custid | aname |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | A |
| 10 | B |

> ```
> SELECT 2
> ```

```
DO $$
DECLARE  
   custIdConstant integer := 10;  
BEGIN  
INSERT INTO groupL(custId, aName) 
SELECT custIdConstant, name1 FROM aName  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM groupL WHERE custId = custIdConstant AND aName = name1);

INSERT INTO groupL(custId, aName) 
SELECT custIdConstant, name2 FROM aName WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM groupL WHERE custId = custIdConstant AND aName = name2);

END $$;
```

> ```
> DO
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM groupL
```

| custid | aname |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | A |
| 10 | B |

> ```
> SELECT 2
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mNEyPwmu)

Comment: Thanks but the issue is moreso that the subquery can be a variable list. It can range from 0 to N I just used two as an example. Something to iterate over this list ya know?

Comment: you would get all column names https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22362/list-all-columns-for-a-specified-table  , iterate trough the result https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32668201/how-to-iterate-over-results-of-query and build a dynamic sql query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12780275/dynamic-sql-query-in-postgres and execute it

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to check for the existence of those rows via a second subquery:

```
INSERT INTO groupL (custId, aName)
SELECT <custId>, a.aName 
FROM artwork as a
WHERE a.title IN (SELECT c.title 
                  FROM classify as c INNER JOIN NEW ON NEW.g_name = c.g_name)
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM groupL as g
                  WHERE g.custId = <custId> AND g.aName = a.aName);
```

You might want to check into [merge](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-merge.html) as well.

Comment: no the first insert was only a example where subqueries work, he wants the rest of the question, it seems thqat it is a part of a trigger function#

Comment: @nbk: Yeah, I've never worked with Postgres triggers so I may be missing something. With a "variable" number of rows though I don't see why you'd break this up into multiple inserts though.